# How do I pass a querystring value into a select statement in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, sql, ado.net

How do I pass a querystring value into a select statement in ASP.NET?

Here's what I've tried:

```
{ 
    string myID = (Request.QueryString["ID"] ?? "0").ToString(); 

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection
        (ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString); 
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT ID, Name, Date, Description FROM MyTable     
                                            where ID=@ID", con); 
    DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
    da.Fill(dt); 
    GV_InlineEditing.DataSource = dt; 
    GV_InlineEditing.DataBind(); 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [`SqlCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx) and add the parameter to it:

```
string query = "SELECT ID, Name, Date, Description FROM MyTable where ID=@ID";
var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", myID);
var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
```